# If $D_1\subseteq D_2$ then the generated sigma-algebras are such that $\sigma(D_1)\subseteq \sigma(D_2)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a set of subsets of $\Omega$. Then, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$ is defined as

$$\sigma(A):= \cap \{\mathcal{F}\; |\; \mathcal{F}\text{ is a }\sigma\text{-algebra and }A\subseteq \mathcal{F} \}$$

From the definition it is clear that $\sigma(A)$ is the smallest $\sigma$ algebra containing $A$.

Now, let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two non-empty family of subsets of a nonempty set $\Omega$ such that $D_1\subseteq D_2$.

I want to prove that $\sigma(D_1)\subseteq \sigma(D_2)$.

I observed that

$A\in D_1$

$\implies A \in D_2$

$\implies A\in \sigma(D_2)$

$\implies D_1 \subseteq \sigma(D_2)$

From here, I don't know how to proceed. I am new to Probability Theory so please be gentle.

Comment: Indeed, $D_1 \subseteq \sigma(D_2)$, thus, you know one sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ with contains $D_1$ (yes, $\mathcal F=\sigma(D_2)$). Looking at the definition of $\sigma(D_1)$, this means that this sigma-algebra $\mathcal F$ appears on the RHS, hence the whole intersection on the RHS is *not larger*, right? That is, $\sigma(D_1)\subseteq\mathcal F$... Oops, the proof is over.

Comment: The RHS of the definition of the generated sigma-algebra, in line 2 of your question.